# Magento Plugin not working - Soap

Tags: magento, soap

I'm trying to get an extension to work in Magento 1.7 but I get this system.log error:

ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant SOAP_1_2 - assumed 'SOAP_1_2'  in /var/www/vhosts/

DEBUG (7): Error fetching parcelshops
2015-01-22T20:09:42+00:00

DEBUG (7): SOAP extension is not loaded.
2015-01-22T20:10:01+00:00

Is it because the soap is not enable on the server?

Best regards
Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Soap extension isn't enabled on your server.

Create a "phpinfo.php" file in your Magento root folder, and add this:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

You can check there if Soap is enabled or not.

[image]

Comment: Hey Mayers. Do you mean  '--enable-soap=shared' in the phpinfo fil or should it be in a separate row?

Comment: It should have its own Soap section. (I edited my reply with a visual)

Comment: Thank you so much Mayers. How do I enabled it then?

Comment: Best thing to do is to contact your hosting provider and ask them to make the change for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is possible to check directly in the script if the specific extension (in this case - `soap`) was enabled:

```
$arrLoadedExtensions = array_map('strtolower', get_loaded_extensions());
$booLoaded = in_array('soap', $arrLoadedExtensions);
```